# inputMask with "N" values

Tags: primefaces, input-mask

how can I put ", " each 4 numbers in a input, I have something like this:

```
<p:inputMask mask="9999, 9999" placeHolder="_"/>
```

But I need "N" values, so I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An input mask can be used to constrain the input, this is constrained at the moment the user enters data into the system. You cannot set with no limit numbers.

I suggest you to use converter instead.

xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText id="input" 
                 converter="numberConverter" 
                 value="#{inputTextView.numberInput}" >
        <p:ajax process="input" 
                update="input" 
                event="blur"/>
    </p:inputText>
</h:form>
```

managedbean

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "inputTextView")
public class InputTextView {

    private String numberInput;

    public String getNumberInput() {
        return numberInput;
    }

    public void setNumberInput(String numberInput) {
        this.numberInput = numberInput;
    }   
}
```

converter

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

/**
 *
 * @author Wittakarn
 */
@FacesConverter("numberConverter")
public class NumberConverter implements Serializable, Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String string) {
        return string.replaceAll(",", "");
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
        String resp = "";
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat;
        if (o != null) {
            decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,####");
            decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            try {
                resp = decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(o.toString()));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return resp;

    }
}
```